# How to fix sub menu not clickable?

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, themes

I'm using generate press and add some megamenu CSS unfortunately upon clicking the submenu it's not clickable here is the link

I tried to use this mega menu to create columns for each sub-menus

https://hrcstaging.wpengine.com/

here is the CSS that I added

https://docs.generatepress.com/article/building-simple-mega-menu/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
    pointer-events: inherit;
}
```

ok this works fine now